# TypeScript. Extract nested type from array of generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Task: get the type from a neighboring field or a neighboring function parameter. The type of this field/parameter is additionally packed into an array and a generic.

```
class Resource<T> {
    value: T;

    constructor(
        dependencies?: Resource<any>[],
        initFunction?: ((dependencyValues: any[]) => void)
    ) {
        // ...
    }
}

const dep1 = new Resource<string>();
const dep2 = new Resource<number>();

const r = new Resource<boolean>(
    [dep1, dep2],
    (deps) => {
        // In current case:
        //  deps: any[]

        // But I need to get real types, so
        //  deps: [string, number]
    }
);
```

The same task can be represented differently, where configuration object will be used instead of constructor parameters.

```
class Resource<T> {
    constructor(config?: ResourceConfig<T>) {
        // ...
    }
}

interface ResourceConfig<T> {
    dependencies?: Resource<any>[];
    init?: ((dependencyValues: any[]) => void);
}
```

So, how can I achieve this?

P.S. Yes, I understand that I can manually specify the type of parameters through `deps: [string, number]`, but I would like to automatically get the necessary types, and not place them manually every time.

I tried different approaches, including infer types, but in the end, the preprocessor still returns `any` or `unknown` type for these fields.

Comment: Here's how I would do it: https://tsplay.dev/w84Zdw

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NlDbGN) meet your needs? You can't have the compiler infer some type arguments while letting you specify others, so you will either need to have some dummy arguments or curried constructors or something.  It would be nice if you actually had a value of the relevant `T` type somewhere; it's often a sign of a problem when you have a type and nothing concrete that actually depends on that type.  Anyway if that approach works for you I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @vr. Static factory function! Yes, this will help, thanks! I noticed that this trick with `K in keyof Deps` decomposition doesn't work well with constructors, but works well with normal functions. But ordinary class member functions or just standalone factory functions are not convenient to use for object initialization. And in your case everything turns out very conveniently. One minus - in this solution, the class generic still has two parameters, and it will be impossible to specify only the first parameter - TS forces you to specify both. But anyway, thanks, you saved my day.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, I understand how your code works (and yes, it solves the problem!), but using a dummy parameter is a wildly inconvenient thing. In our project, we have to declare huge data structures of several hundred resources. And each time passing a dummy parameter there is not convenient and will confuse developers. Moreover, often there are some more complex types than just string or boolean. But thank you, it's a nice new trick to know/

Comment: I think you're going to have something inconvenient/confusing no matter what because of the lack of [ms/TS#26242](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242).  Presumably your ideal code would look like `new Foo<Bar>(baz)`. Your choices will end up looking like `new Foo(null! as Bar, baz)` (as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mbEXoN)) or `new (Foo<Bar>())(baz)` (as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mpjyXw)), or some refactoring involving similar indirection; I'm not sure exactly which one is better for your use case, but each of those requires you to mention `Bar` at least once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another type parameter to `Resource` and let it default to `[]`:

```
class Resource<T, Deps extends Resource<any>[] = []> {
```

You'll notice that now you cannot pass any dependencies, without manually specifying this second type parameter:

```
new Resource<string>([dep1, dep2]); // errors
//                    ~~~~ Type 'Resource<string, []>' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.(2322)
```

That is because it has not been provided and so it defaults to `[]`. Since [partial type inference](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26242) has yet to be implemented, to get around this, you can create a curried static factory function that simply passes on its parameters and type parameters to the constructor:

```
static create<T>() {
    return <Deps extends Resource<any>[] = []>(
        ...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Resource<T, Deps>>
    ) => new Resource<T, Deps>(...args);
}
```

where the constructor can now use `Deps` and provide the correct types for the callback:

```
/** @internal */
constructor(
    dependencies?: [...Deps],
    initFunction?: (dependencyValues: {
        [K in keyof Deps]: Deps[K] extends Resource<infer T> ? T : never;
    }) => void
) {}
```

Inside, we infer `Deps` as a tuple using [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types). Then, we map over the tuple using a mapped type, inferring the resource's value type.

Now you can use it here:

```
const dep1 = Resource.create<string>()();
const dep2 = Resource.create<number>()();

const r = Resource.create<boolean>()([dep1, dep2], ([str, num]) => {
    str;
    //  ^? string
    num;
    //  ^? number
});
```

If you don't need to pass dependencies, you can also use the old constructor:

```
const dep1 = new Resource<string>();
const dep2 = new Resource<string>();
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBKCmED2BXATseAeAKgGmgBF4AHGeADwBd4A7AExgWXUyzFoE8A+AbQF1oAXmgDu0AN4AoaLOgA3MCBTwAhAC5oOANxSZcgPQAqI9AACAS1o00tJdCMH9s4EloQqaFMCpI0ACmc5WXpSOlDaYAtEAH5NXgA6JOIyfjwg4KsLKgAxFEiqCzc46H9QknC6YE4ANSUVCE1pYJa5XgBpaCtoAGt4TiQAMyJSCH5NFIgOwUoaBiZEVAxsK0H4NC1xGK1oTVp4eXXdVtkAXwBKYXF5JAt6IMuJU71gjzBC4GhgNHh37BxuP5Hhk5D8qOhaNAsJNoLNwgsWMt2Fw+IIRGJAicWkkEmA0ABzRrQADCbg8Xh8fgACniwABbeA2CBYKicCpDOCLVj-AiTbjcEGyS5CcT7ADunMRbHwIzIgJxeMJ52Ocmezz0rncVGg5QAjMJoOLJUs2OSrPjAcqpJqPDrSAAmA1G5gm7Bm2gWoG6a1k7UbEQu7kJb6-GhYABGSCQIF+tEt-l4eoI5XtaVKvHJBFoKDp-GF4macnJKtkBgMsgAejEgtm6SXoGXK9WLrogA)